# How to connect toolbar icon with CollapsingToolbarLayout listener?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I try find solution to connect icon inside my **Toolbar** with **CoordinatorLayout** and **CollapsingToolbarLayout**. I have to accomplish the following effect, when I scroll my content to up and **CollapsingToolbarLayout** collapses then I want to fade out my **Toolbar** icon. Below is my layout:

**activity_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/app_bg_color"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                fresco:overlayImage="@drawable/grid_item_bg"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_photo_small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/noimage"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/large_text"
        android:textColor="@color/menu_text_color"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Any ideas?